# Android memory game

Tags: android, graphics, android-glide

I have problems with allocate in my app.  Can I use glide on graphics and minimize this problem?

```
buttonGraphic[0] = R.drawable.memory3;
buttonGraphic[1] = R.drawable.memory4;
buttonGraphic[2] = R.drawable.memory5;
buttonGraphic[3] = R.drawable.memory6;
buttonGraphic[4] = R.drawable.memory7;
buttonGraphic[5] = R.drawable.memory1;
buttonGraphic[6] = R.drawable.memory8;
buttonGraphic[7] = R.drawable.memory2;
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Didn't understand...

Comment: I'm assuming there is an OutOfMemoryException because he "can't allocate" so I think "can't allocate heap"

Comment: In error i have this: "Failed to allocate a 142850316 byte allocation with 33553088 free bytes and 69MB until OOM" so I want graphics optimize with glide or somethig.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood,(Correct me if I'm wrong) you have a OutOfMemoryException, meaning no more heap for your app.

**Assuming your error is with creating a Bitmap object**

First, I assume buttonGraphic is an integer. If you want to assign a drawable to a Bitmap, you have to do something like this:(NOTE! There are many ways to create a bitmap instance. This is one, not the way)

```
... = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources()/*context.getResources()*/, R.drawable.memory8);
```

The buttonGraphic array has to be of type Bitmap if you assign it as a bitmap

**Assuming your error is an OutOfMemoryException**

This is a difficult error, as you use more memory(heap/ram) than your app is granted access to.

The easiest way to resolve this error is to get more memory. This is easily done with this line in your manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Yes, I have this problem OutOfMemoryException. I try this what u say. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixing OutOfMemoryException by setting android:largeHeap to "true" is a very bad decision, it's a workaround but not a resolution. 
Me Recommendations are:
1. Try to decrease image sizes (from 1000*1000px to 200*200px for example)
2. Rework layout/design so u don't need to have 7 buttons with heavy drawables, think of different UI
3. Use picasso